# I want the modal to display only when the input is not empty

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
I want the modal to show after the user has fill the form, But don't know how to do that. Am very new in javascript.
```

This is the html form

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
 <h3 class="panel-title">
 <div align="center">
<p>
 Funds Transfer
 </h3>
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">

<div align="center">
<p> 
Bank of lgbt Funds Transfer Service makes it easy to transfer funds to other beneficiaries within the bank or to other domestic bank.<br>
To effect transfer of funds, please complete and submit the form below. Please note that all account numbers are required to be NUBAN compliant. </br>

<div id="middle">

<table class="">

       <tr>
          <th>
       <label for="funds transfr" >*Funds Transfer Type: </label>
      </th>
          <td><p>
            <select name="fundstransfr" maxlength="20" tabindex="108" >
              <option value=" ">   </option>
              <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
              <option value="External">External</option>
            </select>
          </p>
            <p>&nbsp; </p>
          </td>

   <tr>
         <th>

           <label for= "transfr from" >*Transfer from: </label>
          </th>
          <td><p>
            <select name="transfrfrom" maxlength="20" tabindex="108">
              <option value=" ">   </option>
              <option value="Premier Account">Premier Account</option>
              <option value="Credit Card">Credit Card</option>
            </select>
          </p>
            <p>&nbsp; </p>
          </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>

    <tr>
          <th>
            <label for="amount">*Amount:</label> </th>
          <td> <p>
            <input type="number" name="amount" value="" placeholder="0.00" maxlength="30" size="12" tabindex="106">
          </p>
            <p>&nbsp; </p></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>

    <tr>
          <th>
               <label for="Beneficiary Name">*Beneficiary Name:</label>
      </th>
          <td> <input type="text" name="BeneficiaryName" value="" maxlength="40" size ="30"tabindex="107"></td>
      <td><p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>

<tr>

            <th>
               <label for="Beneficiary Bank" >*Beneficiary Bank:</label></th>
            <td><p>
              <select name="BeneficiaryBank" maxlength="20" tabindex="108">
                <option value="">  </option>
                <option value="">Bank of trump</option>
                <option value="">Obama bank</option>

              </select>
            </p>
            <p>&nbsp; </p></td>

     <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th><label for="Beneficiary Accountr" >*Beneficiary Account No (NUBAN):</label></th>
          <td><p>
            <input type="number" name="BeneficiaryAccount" value="" placeholder="N/A" maxlength="20" tabindex="116" maxlength="20" tabindex="114"/>
          </p>
            <p>&nbsp; </p></td></form>

    <tr>
          <th> <label for="Payment Reference" class="btn-group-lg">
            Payment Reference:</label>          </th>
          <td><input type="text" name="PaymentReference" value=""></td><br>

          </table>





><br>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
 <button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >Proceed</button>
```

This is the modal window

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
 <spal class="close1">&times;</spal>
 <h4 class="modal-title">Please enter your secure Transaction Code.</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
          <label for="TransactionCode">*Transaction Code:</label>

      <input type="text" name="TransactionCode" value="" maxlength="40" size ="30"tabindex="107">

          <p> For Transaction Code <a href="#">click here</a></p>
        </div>



      <div class="modal-footer">


          <button type="button" id ="myBtn2"class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Proceed</button>      
     </div>


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">

 <span class="close2">&times;</span>

 <h4 class="modal-title">Please enter your secure Tax verification code.</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
          <label for="taxcode">*Tax Verification Code:</label>

      <input type="text" name="taxcode" value="" maxlength="40" size ="30"tabindex="107">

          <p> For Tax Verification Code <a href="#">click here</a></p>
        </div>



      <div class="modal-footer">


          <button type="button" id ="myBtn2"class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Proceed</button>      
     </div>


</div>
</div>

  </div>  


          </div>  
</div>
```

This is the script

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2'); 

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spal = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close2")[0];


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
spal.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

After the user have fill the form and click on the proceed button the modal should pop up but if the user did not fill all the form the modal should not display and and an error message should alert.. When the modal display then the user should fill the 1st modal form with a code 123456, if the user did not put anything or give a wrong code the 2nd modal should not show but if he/she does it should display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add and **id** attribute for each field of the form with the *same value* as the name attribute.

```
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    if( document.getElementById('fundstransfr').value != '' &&
        document.getElementById('transfrfrom').value != '' &&
        document.getElementById('amount').value != '' &&
        document.getElementById('BeneficiaryName').value != '' &&
        document.getElementById('BeneficiaryBank').value != '' &&
        document.getElementById('BeneficiaryAccount').value != '' &&
        document.getElementById('PaymentReference').value != '') {

        modal.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        alert('All fields are required.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, its working i appreciate, kindly help me with the remaining ones. When the modal is displayed, the user should fill the 1st modal form with a code 123456, if the user did not put anything or give a wrong code the 2nd modal should not show but if he/she does it should display. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have modify all and it is now working perfectly... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your forms need to each be wrapped their own in a `<form> ... </form>` construct for the `<input>` elements to work correctly, and to be able to submit the form data.

Your Javascript code needs validation in the button handlers.  If the validation fails, display your error alert, and return `false` to stop processing the form submission.

Make sure you validate the user's entries on the server after the form is submitted.

You should consider using something like jQuery rather than raw Javascript, it will make, e.g., selecting form elements, a lot easier.

Comment: Am new to programming as a whole that is why i need your help. Can you help me to re-edit the code as you have just suggested.

Comment: When I was new to programming, many years ago, I read books with exercises that taught me how to do programming.  If you have someone else write your code for you, you will never learn how to do it yourself.  Books are your friends, don't forget them ;)